# Equivalent of Swift's .map in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, swift, dictionary

Say I have `NSArray *x = @[@1, @2, @3, @4];`

Now say I want an array like `@[@2, @4, @6, @8]`

In good ole Swift, I can just do :

```
xDoubled = x.map({($0) * 2})
```

Can someone tell me how I can do this in Objective-C without doing -

```
NSMutableArray *xDoubled = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSInteger xVal in x) {
    [xDoubled addObject:xVal * 2];
}
```

?

Comment: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5364414152704000 (and mine's a duplicate of a much older request). There is no map method in Cocoa today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSArray` doesn't have a `map` method. It has an `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` method (and related ones) that do something similar; they don't automatically convert an object into another and return another array, but you can do that manually easily enough. However, they're not all that much different than your example.

I wrote a library called [collections](https://github.com/mdippery/collections) that adds a map method (and other collections-oriented methods) to `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, and `NSSet`, though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't necessarily recommend this, but you can do some funky stuff leveraging categories and Key-Value Coding. For example:

```
@interface NSNumber (DoubledValue)
- (NSNumber*) doubledValue;
@end

@implementation NSNumber (DoubledValue)
- (NSNumber*) doubledValue
{
    return @([self doubleValue] * 2);
}
@end

xDoubled = [x valueForKey:@"doubledValue"];
```

In general, for any operation that can be expressed as a key or key path to a property of the object, `-valueForKey[Path]:` acts as a primitive form of `map()`.

Comment: This is very neat and actually accomplishes what OP wants in my opinion. Thanks for that.